# Make password appear censored in bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am going to make this short and simple. I am making a bash script where the user needs to enter their root password using the read command and it will be stored in a variable. What I don't like is that their password is clearly visible as they type it. I want their password to be shown as stars or be invisible like when normally entering root password. I don't mind using tput. How can I do this?

Comment: Have a look at the read builtin's `-s` option (type `help read` from the bash prompt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read command has an option to prevent input from showing when you type it.

```
echo "Enter the password: "
read -s password
#Print the password
echo $password
```

Comment: You really want to use `read -sp "Enter the password: " password` to have the prompt appear on the same line.

Comment: Yup, but that is giving an error on my mac for some reason.

Comment: @PrathikRajendranM What's the error?

Comment: % read -sp "Enter password:" password                                                                14-08-23 - 9:23:02
read: -p: no coprocess

Comment: `echo -n "Enter password: "` ...